# Book with cows as incubators

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to get the title of a book where human embryos are implanted into cows and birthed in "Creches". Can anyone identify this book and author for me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall when you read this or any other details about the book?  You should review the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for story-id questions to see if they help you remember any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. If there is a wrong answer, please explain why it doesn't match, particularly if it helps provide more details you can edit into your question ("No, that can't be it. My story has a Spanish Dentist as its main character.")

Comment: Could this be [The House of the Scorpion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_of_the_Scorpion)? I remember cows incubating human clones early in the novel...

Comment: @c-x-berger Found that one too, but it didn't duck enough boxes for me. That said, it seems like a valid partial answer.

Answer (score 18):

You might be looking for Frederik Pohl's *[Outnumbering the Dead](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11909)*. While the main plot is about humanity being rendered immortal prior to birth, and the main character, Rafiel, being a rare case of the procedure failing (and thus him being doomed to die eventually), there is a sub-plot where he discusses having a baby with Alegretta and indeed, the embryo is incubated within a cow at a creche.

Searching for `science fiction novel embryos cow creche` got me a Google Books excerpt from *[The Best of the Best, Volume 2: 20 Years of the Best Short Science Fiction](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q3oghaDivvAC&pg=PA363&lpg=PA363&dq=science%20fiction%20novel%20embryos%20cow%20creche&source=bl&ots=uNwdzpjYY3&sig=ACfU3U2LOrMgSiQ2-sFJ4y6D3Z3asPc7qg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie5oeNttrqAhXBhHIEHfxiCz4Q6AEwEXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=science%20fiction%20novel%20embryos%20cow%20creche&f=false)*. Searching for some keywords from there, `sonora arcology rafiel alegretta`, found me [an online copy of the issue of *Asimov's](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v16n12n13_1992-11/page/n243/mode/2up)* that contained the story. Here is an excerpt from [page 244](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v16n12n13_1992-11/page/n251) and [page 258](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v16n12n13_1992-11/page/n265/):

> She was waving a tomograph, and when she handed it to him he was astonished to see that it was an image of what looked like a three-month fetus. He blinked at her in surprise. “Yours?”
>
> She nodded ecstatically. “They just sent it from the creche,” she explained, nervous with pleasure. “Isn’t it *tres belle?*"

…

> Then it was Rafiel’s turn to blunder. “What sort of surrogate are you using?” he asked, to make conversation, and she gave him a sharp look.
>
> “Did somebody tell you? No? Well, it’s cow,” she said, and waited to see what his response would be. She seemed aggrieved. When all he did was nod noncomittally, she said, “Charlus wanted to use something fancier. Do you think I did the right thing, Rafiel? Insisting on an ordinary cow surrogate, I mean? So many people are using water buffalo now. . . .”

It's a slightly weak match, in that this is a brief scene in the book, and they actually only use the word "creche" once, but it does match your question. If this is not the correct answer, it would be helpful for you to edit the question with details that you now know because they do not match this book.

Comment: Also by Frederik Pohl, humans being incubated in cows is also a plot point in [The Annals of the Heechee](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Annals_of_the_Heechee) - the last book in the Heechee saga (which starts with Gateway).

Comment: @Paul it seems like you should develop your comment into an answer.

Comment: @JamesJenkins The word "creche" doesn't appear in the book, so without more details from the OP I don't know if it's a good answer or not, I figured I'd comment in case the correct answer is a combination of the two and to point out that it might be a recurring theme in Pohl's work in case someone wants to investigate his other works.